# Pandas does uppercase/ lowercase mean anything in dtypes?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dtype

`Float32` vs `float32`?

What is the purpose of uppercase vs lowercase dtypes in Pandas?

Uppercase seems more error prone: `TypeError: object cannot be converted to a FloatingDtype`.

```py
dtype = {
    'doom_float64': 'Float64'
    , 'radiance_float32': 'Float32'
    , 'temperature_float': 'float'
    , 'moonday_int64': 'Int64'
    , 'month_int32': 'Int32'
    , 'color_uint8': 'UInt8'
    , 'shape_int': 'int'
    , 'weekday_object': 'object'
    , 'hour_object': 'string'
    , 'kingdom_category': 'category'
}
```

```py
>>> df.dtypes

doom_float64          Float64
radiance_float32      Float32
temperature_float     float64
weekday_object         object
hour_object            string
moonday_int64           Int64
month_int32             Int32
color_uint8             UInt8
shape_int               int64
kingdom_category     category
dtype: object
```

`Pandas v1.2.0`

Comment: I am not sure, but could it be that the capital letter is used to differentiate the data type from the NumPy’s one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html) for example.

> pandas can represent integer data with possibly missing values using
> arrays.IntegerArray. This is an extension types implemented within
> pandas.
>
> Or the string alias "Int64" (note the capital "I", to differentiate
> from NumPy’s 'int64' dtype:

Capitalized types are pandas types, while uncapitalized types are numpy types.

One feature of pandas types is the ability to support nan, which is not a standard IEEE for non floats.

Comment: IEEE doesn't have an opinion on integer arithmetic (sadly) let alone generic non float columns.

Comment: Also, what you probably mean is that Pandas supports pd.NA in nullable columns, which is different from NaN. In fact, nullable float columns support NaN (invalid operation, e.g. 0/0) and NA (missing data) side by side